# How to create a custom styled 404 page in remix

Tags: remix.run

Hello how do i style and create a custom 404 page in remix.

I want to override the current 404 page with my own content when a path is recognized.

[image]

Comment: Hey Bobby did @corygibbons answer solve your question? If so please consider marking it as solved. Also wanted to share an example in my repo https://github.com/CanRau/canrau.com/blob/main/app/routes/%24lang/__main.tsx#L205 let me know if you've got any further questions

Comment: Yes sorry I have solved this issue. I could not see the close button for this issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can edit the `CatchBoundary` in `root.tsx`/`root.tsx` and return whatever you want to render.

```js
export function CatchBoundary() {
  const caught = useCatch();

  return (
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Oops!</title>
        <Meta />
        <Links />
      </head>
      <body>
        <h1>
          {caught.status} {caught.statusText}
        </h1>
        <Scripts />
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

Relevant documentation here: https://remix.run/docs/en/v1/guides/not-found#root-catch-boundary

Comment: Using a CatchBoundary will take you outside the render happy path. A splat route throwing a 404 not found would keep you inside the happy path, allowing to show a custom message, while also correctly throwing a 404 not found.

Answer (score 9):

### TLDR;

Create a `routes/$.jsx` file. Optionally you can add this loader in that route in order to get an HTTP 404 status code.

```
export const loader = () => {
  return json(null, { status: 404 });
};
```

[Link to doc](https://remix.run/docs/en/v1/guides/routing#splats)

### A wider perspective

You should show custom ui on 3 types of errors:

- unexpected errors like `Cannot read properties of undefined` ([ErrorBoundary](https://remix.run/docs/en/v1/api/conventions#errorboundary) in `root.tsx`)
- expected errors like custom logic `return json({ errors: [{code: "unpaid", message: "user didnt pay"}] })` ([CatchBoundary](https://remix.run/docs/en/v1/api/conventions#catchboundary) in `root.tsx`)
- 404 ([Splat route $.tsx](https://remix.run/docs/en/v1/guides/routing#splats) in `routes/`)

Also you can define a ErrorBoundary/CatchBoundary for each nested route if you think that will give the user a better ux (like in tabs or folders).

Comment: This will make the HTTP response 200 OK, which is not correct. You should also show how to throw an HTTP: 404 not found.

Comment: @AndréCasal done, thanks. LMK if you know a better way

Comment: No, that's pretty much the best one, thanks for improving your answer 

Answer (score 1):

You should use `ErrorBoundary` using nested pathless layout for this. This way we properly handle status code we throw in routes.

credits:
https://sergiodxa.com/tutorials/create-multiple-top-level-layouts-in-remix

`/routes/_layout.tsx`:

```
import type { MetaFunction } from '@remix-run/node';
import { type ErrorResponse, Outlet, isRouteErrorResponse, useRouteError } from '@remix-run/react';

import { NotFoundSection } from '~/components/not-found-section';

export const meta: MetaFunction = ({ error }) => {
    if (error) {
        return [
            ...((error as ErrorResponse).status === 404 ? [{ title: 'Page Not Found' }] : []),
            { name: 'robots', content: 'noindex, nofollow' },
        ];
    }
};

export default function Layout() {
    return <Outlet />;
}

export function ErrorBoundary() {
    const error = useRouteError();

    if (isRouteErrorResponse(error)) {
        if (error.status === 404) {
            return <NotFoundSection />;
        }

        throw new Error(`${error.status} ${error.statusText}`);
    }

    throw new Error(error instanceof Error ? error.message : 'Unknown Error');
}
```

Upd: Don't forget to add splat route for non-matching routes
`/routes/_layout.$.tsx`:

```
export const loader = () => {
    throw new Response('Not Found', { status: 404 });
};

export default function SplatRoute() {
    return <></>;
}
```

Then prepend each route should follow this layout, like `/routes/_layout._page.($slug).tsx`.

I my example, I want to render view (which will be nested from `<Outlet />` in `root.tsx`) only for 404 status code, for other errors I `throw` new error to handle in `root.tsx` ErrorBoundary.